# Bridging vulkan structs

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm trying to create a simple wrapper for vulkan.

Each vulkan struct is bridged with a C++ class that can be used. A class holds an instance to the original vulkan struct like:

```
{
  ..
  private:
    VkQueueFamilyProperties instance = {};
}
```

Functions like [vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties.html) are bridged too. E.g. this method expects an array of structs as its third parameter `pQueueFamilyProperties`.

I create such an array as following:

```
  std::vector<S*> arr(len);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    arr[i] = &my_class->instance;
  };
  out = arr.data();
```

Passing this array now to a vulkan function results in random crashing of the program, since the vulkan function expects an array of structs, not an array of struct references. How do I pass the instance member of my bridge class to the vulkan function?

Am i missing something basic here?

Thanks for your time!

Edit: `vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties` updates the struct members of the passed `pQueueFamilyProperties`. So how do i make the vulkan function update an array of `my_class->instance` structs and their members?

Edit2: I think I found the main problem, filling an vector ends up with creating a copy of the set value. To create a reference you just fill a pointer. But as said I cannot use references, since the vulkan function expect's an array of structs, not an array of references to structs.

Comment: If you need an "array of structs", then use `std::vector<S>` and not use the address-of operator in the assignment?

Comment: This way, after calling the vulkan function the properties of my_class->instance doesn't change at all

Comment: Then you need to copy the opposite direction as well.

Comment: Vulkan functions expect "arrays of structs" not "arrays of pointers to structs". So one way or another You need to provide "arrays of structs" however You construct them. It's probably more reasonable to copy original values on initialization and keep them inside Your wrapper classes and then just provide when needed. And if something doesn't work, then You probably did something wrong (it's hard for us to guess). Besides keeping pointers to structs can be dangerous because those pointers can easily become invalid when original variables get destroyed.

Comment: "*I'm trying to create a simple wrapper for vulkan.*" Stop doing that. There is no point in writing a wrapper around a simple data structure.

Comment: @NicolBolas I disagree. There is a vulkan.hpp which is a simple C++ wrapper for simple data structures. But for convenience this might come in handy. And writing own wrapper is a very good way to learn Vulkan or any other library.

Comment: @Ekzuzy: `vulkan.hpp` should not be held up as an example of good C++. It is absolutely littered with UB.

Comment: @NicolBolas Maybe it is. But it also shows there is a demand for such wrappers (auto-destructors are fantastic!!).

Comment: @Ekzuzy: "*auto-destructors are fantastic!!*" If you're talking about `UniqueHandle`, sure. But there is nothing about `UniqueHandle` which requires wrapping "simple data structures" like `VkQueueFamilyProperties` and the like. That is *pointless*.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yup, I was talking about `UniqueHandles`. And true, I agree that wrapping such simple structures like `VkQueueFamilyProperties` makes no sense. But I understand why people want constructors filling in all the default fields for them (like structure type and pNext) and requiring them to provide values for all the other required members (to not forget about them).